# Recursive Trigger to sync tables in separate databases

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to sync three separate databases tables. My goal is to have any update done on any table in one database would in turn update the others. The purpose is for three separate sites. db1.table has all the data, db2.table and db3.table have certain amounts of the data but any change done need to remain in sync and preferable close to real time. Since triggers are fast I could basically replicate any SQL statement from one table to another thus keeping everything in sync.

Right now I am using triggers in this fashion:

db1.table -> trigger on update to update db2.table
db2.table -> trigger on update to update db3.table

This works great if I only update on db1 but I try to loop it around from bd3 to db1 and I get the MySQL recursion error:

"Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger."

My code is written so if there is nothing to update then it doesn't update the other table so it wouldn't loop through more than once.

Is there a workaround or a different method besides triggers?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't just reference one master table in one of the databases and centralize the data there?